# Extraneous input '\' expecting {')', ','}. Query working in sql notebook cell but not in databricks connect

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

When executing the following query

```
SELECT * FROM companies JOIN employments on companies.company_normalized LIKE CONCAT('%',
    replace(employments.displayname_normalized, '\\', ''), '%') or employments.displayname_normalized LIKE CONCAT(
    '%', replace(companies.company_normalized,'\\', ''), '%')
```

it works fine on databricks sql notebook cell.

However, when attempting to run this same query using spark sql executor, ie spark.sql(query), this errors out saying:
Extraneous input '' expecting {')', ','} within the replace clause.

Is there a fix for this?

Comment: Try replacing \\ by \\\\ when using `spark.sql()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need either a single backslash, if you are using regex:

```
spark.sql("SELECT * FROM companies JOIN employments on companies.company_normalized LIKE CONCAT('%',
replace(employments.displayname_normalized, '\', ''), '%') or employments.displayname_normalized LIKE CONCAT(
'%', replace(companies.company_normalized,'\', ''), '%')")
```

or you need to escape slashes, then you need to double escape using "\\\\":

```
spark.sql("SELECT * FROM companies JOIN employments on companies.company_normalized LIKE CONCAT('%',
replace(employments.displayname_normalized, '\\\\', ''), '%') or employments.displayname_normalized LIKE CONCAT(
'%', replace(companies.company_normalized,'\\\\', ''), '%')")
```

Comment: does this still apply if I want to replace the \ character?